# How to write a program (preferably in Python) to stream the live feed from a remote public webcam?

Tags: python, streaming, webcam

I need to write a program (preferably in Python) to stream (retrieve) the live feed from a public online remote webcam.

The input of the program should be the link (or the IP) of the webcam. For example: http://shapiro.cam.lib.umich.edu/view/index.shtml

The expected output of the program should be the individual frames of the live feed at the frame rate provided by the camera. I should be able to store these frames locally as a video, or even just showing them.

How could I write this program? Is there any sample code? Are there any tutorials for this process? What kind of libraries should I use to achieve my goal.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I know how to do this! Let me write you up the answer :)

Comment: @SamTubb +1 for the enthusiasm. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the VideoCapture module available here: http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/

After downloading and installing this you will need to download dropbox, a file hoster of sorts which is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/

You will also need pygame :3 I'm sure you know what that is! 
(available here: http://www.pygame.org/news.html)

Then write a python script like this and place it in your dropbox public folder:

```
import pygame,time
from VideoCapture import Device
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=550)
cam = Device()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
pygame.display.set_caption('Casting...')
while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            exit()
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        cam.saveSnapshot('image.jpg')
    except:
        pass
```

Then after that, make a html file with a code like this:

```
<html>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Live Cam" height="200" width="200">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
</html>
```

Then after that.. use this video to get your page on the web (using your html file of course):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NG15HHwAtwU

Comment: Any idea on how to do it without dropbox? As in how to store this on a hard disk?

Comment: Dropbox just puts the file on a live web page for everyone to see.. so yeah, just put the files on a hard disk.